# Why does my computer keep pausing when I run a progam using the USB-serial ports?

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb

I've written a program that uses three serial ports (two serial ports are on one USB -> serial connector, the other serial port is on its own USB -> serial connector).  When I'm running the program, every 5 seconds or so, my computer stops responding, as if the kernel is busy doing something.  I'm not writing any files, so it's not flushing to disk, and I'm not running out of memory, so it's not swapping.  What else could it be?  could it be flushing the serial port or something?  That would be weird, because I wait for a response from the serial ports before I write the next bit of data to them.

It happens less if I don't use the last serial port (the one on it's own USB port).

More info:

- debian lenny (also tried squeeze)
- linux 2.6.26-2-686 (also tried 2.6.32-5-686)
- not using ftdi_sio, using libftd2xx1.0.2 (also tried 1.0.4)

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg`? It could be that you have noise or a poor USB connection and it detaching/reattaching.

Comment: dmesg doesn't have any output relatet to that and the USB to Serial is directly soldered onto the mainboard so unfortunately thats not the Problem.

Comment: You might want to try SystemTap to put some dynamic probes into the kernel and figure out what's happening that way.

Comment: Can use system tap because there's no dbg kernel for 2.6.26-2-686, and I'm running on a 1GB stick, so there isn't enough space for a dbg kernel, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libftd2xx seems to be the problem.  It changes its thread's priority and seems to busy wait or something that seems to take over the system.  Giving user's access to the usb devices in /proc/bus/usb and running the program as a normal user seems to work fine, so I'm not sure why libftd2xx is changing thread priorities.

Comment: There was a bug in GNU Java a few years ago that solidly locked up the system when you ran Eclipse as root - by incorrectly setting the process priority to real time! Maybe this is a similar bug? I'd report it.

Comment: I'd submit a patch if libftd2xx was open source.  I'll contact their support team, but based on experience with other companies, I expect an unrelated and incompetent reply.